# Is gradient descent guaranteed to converge to a local minimum (if it doesn't diverge)?

Tags: optimization, gradient-descent

A few times in the literature, I have seen it suggested that higher learning rates can be bad because gradient descent may approach the neighbourhood of a minimum, but then "bounce around" the minimum and never reach it.

But I wonder if this is possible? Once bound to some region where the objective function is low, can gradient descent really keep moving indefinitely (implying that it will eventually start to cycle)? My intuition says that gradient descent will approach the local minimum, meaning the gradients become shallower and the updates become smaller, which entails convergence, and convergence must be to that local minimum. But I am not sure.

Note: I am not asking whether gradient descent is guaranteed to converge to a **global** minimum (clearly not, it can settle in a suboptimal local minimum), nor am I asking whether it is guaranteed to converge at all (again no, if the learning rate is too high it will diverge; this question is about when the learning rate is not high enough to cause divergence).